# HTML navigation bar problems (active state)

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble setting up my navigation bars active state.
I want the background color to change when a is active.

I've added a code snippet below:

```css
nav {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 38.5px;
  padding-bottom: 38.5px;
  padding-left: 21px;
  padding-right: 21px;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3a9eb2;
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #3a9eb2;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #000000;
}
/* problem*/

nav li a:active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">RT SERIES</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ATV NR6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But when I run the webpage not the active link does not change color, can any one help

Comment: It's working fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE → the background changes to white. Are you sure you understand how `:active` is supposed to work?

Comment: You know how the `:active` state works? It's when you click on an item -> https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/72qur8wo/ basically if you click fast the effect might be blunt, you can hold your click to see it more clearly

Answer (score 1):

The `:active` state of an element is applied, when you actually click an element. For this case, your code works fine. More information about [`:active` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive).

If you mean active as the current page, you will need to apply an additional class via Javascript or PHP.

```css
nav {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
li {
  float: left;
}
nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding-top: 38.5px;
  padding-bottom: 38.5px;
  padding-left: 21px;
  padding-right: 21px;
  background-color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3a9eb2;
  font-size: 20px;
}
nav li a:hover {
  background-color: #3a9eb2;
  opacity: 0.7;
  color: #000000;
}

/* problem*/
nav li a:active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.htm">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">RT SERIES</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ATV NR6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

`a:active` means the state *while* a new page is called, i.e. from the moment when you click on the link until the new page begins to load. Usually this is very short, so you hardly ever see that state.

"active link" often means: the menu entry/link of the current page, which via javascript gets assigned a class like "active", so that would be `<a href="pages/start.php" class="active">Start</a>`

Plus: In your case all links except the first one point to local anchors/IDs on the same page, so a simple javascript as mentioned before would not work in this case.

So i know, this is not a solution to your problem, but it's an answer to why it doesn't work as you obiously expect it.